# Merging DataFrames by Datetime with pd.merge is not possible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes which I need to merge. Both has same datetimes. I need to compare the datetimes and add the values of DF A to corresponding DF B rows by datetime. Let's look to the dataframes:

df["Date"]:

```
2013    2016-06-06
2174    2016-06-07
1432    2016-06-08
2035    2016-06-09
278     2016-06-10
2250    2016-06-11
908     2016-06-12
702     2016-06-13
1982    2016-06-14
630     2016-06-15
Name: Date, Length: 81, dtype: object
```

stocks["Date"]

```
47   2016-06-02
48   2016-06-03
49   2016-06-06
50   2016-06-07
51   2016-06-08
52   2016-06-09
53   2016-06-10
54   2016-06-13
55   2016-06-14
56   2016-06-15
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

When I try to merge the dataframes by:

```
df.merge(stocks, left_on='Date', right_on='Date')
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-72-f2ca0c92995e>", line 1, in <module>
    df.merge(stocks, left_on='Date', right_on='Date')
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6379, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator, validate=validate)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 60, in merge
    validate=validate)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 554, in __init__
    self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 984, in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Comment: They are different dtypes - 'object' vs 'datetime' Use `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])` first

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from the snippet of the Date column; all dates don't match.
using simply `df.merge(stocks)` should work anyway.
you could also use `df.join(stocks)` which as sentdex sensei once said "index is honored".
if you could be more specific and provide a portion of your dataframes the answers would become more tailored to your situation.